# How to capture cut and paste action in file watcher using C#

Tags: c#, paste, filesystemwatcher

I have written file watcher functionality to focus on particular directory activities. I can read all events like creating ,deleting ,renaming and changing the file/folder.

But i don't know how to handle cut and paste scenario, since for "cut" results as  firing  delete event i and "paste" results as  create event firing.

how to handle cut and paste scenario? Any advice on this.

Comment: This is just a guess, but I assume all cut/copy operations involve the clipboard. Try to monitor that and see if it works for you somehow.

Comment: @FrankWhite nice idea! Post it as answer!

Answer (score 4):

Here ya go! Monitor the clipboard for cut/copy/paste operations :)

Comment: Thanks for the idea... i have tried  the clipboard function,but the problem is  filesystemwatcher delete and create event raises after cut and paste operation completed.At this time clipboard loses its data and Clipboard.ContainsFileDropList() method returns false... any help on this...

Answer (score 1):

On a delete, you could store the file that was deleted, and on create, check to see if they are the same. Then you know it was a cut and paste.